# can not get all column values separately but instead get all values in one column postgresql --9.5

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_locations(
    location_word varchar(50)
    ) 
RETURNS TABLE
(
    country varchar(50),
    city varchar(50)
)
AS $$
DECLARE
location_word_ varchar(50);
BEGIN
location_word_:=concat(location_word, '%');
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(' (SELECT c.country, ''''::varchar(50) as city FROM webuser.country c 
                                    WHERE lower(c.country)  LIKE %L  LIMIT 1)
                                UNION
                                (SELECT c.country,ci.city FROM webuser.country c
                                    JOIN webuser.city ci ON c.country_id=ci.country_id
                                    WHERE lower(ci.city) LIKE %L LIMIT 4)', 
                                    location_word_,
                                    location_word_ )    ;

END
$$ language PLPGSQL STABLE;

SELECT public.get_locations('a'::varchar(50));
```

I get this;

```
+get_locations   +
+record          +
------------------
+(Andorra,"")    + 
+(Germany,Aach)  +
+(Germany,Aalen) +
+(Germany,Achim) +
+(Germany,Adenau)+
```

How can i place/get the values column by column like below? Because otherwise i can not match the values correctly. I should get the values column by column as countries and cities etc.

```
|country         | city       |
-------------------------------
| Andorra        | ""         |
| Germany        | Aach       |
| Germany        | Aalen      |
| Germany        | Achim      |
| Germany        | Adenau     |
```

Comment: Call the function in `FROM` clause: `SELECT * FROM public.get_locations('a'::varchar(50))`

Comment: yes correct thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is declared as `returns table` so you have to use it like a table:

```
SELECT *
FROM public.get_locations('a'::varchar(50));
```

---

Unrelated, but:

Your function is way too complicated, you don't need dynamic SQL, nor do you need a PL/pgSQL function.

You can simplify that to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_locations(p_location_word varchar(50)) 
   RETURNS TABLE(country varchar(50), city varchar(50))
AS $$
(SELECT c.country, ''::varchar(50) as city 
 FROM webuser.country c 
 WHERE lower(c.country) LIKE concat(p_location_word, '%')
 LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT c.country ,ci.city 
 FROM webuser.country c
   JOIN webuser.city ci ON c.country_id = ci.country_id
 WHERE lower(ci.city) LIKE concat(p_location_word, '%')
 LIMIT 4)
$$ 
language SQL;
```